# Is there an algorithm to generate graph edges given amount of vertices and edges per node?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there currently an algorithm that given the number of vertices / nodes `n`, and the number of edges per node `l`, output all graph edges?

If not, is there an algorithm that can tell if such graph is possible?

In both cases, this is an undirected, loop-free graph.

Comment: Such a graph is not unique, not even up to isomorphism. Thus, it would be hard to find an algorithm to generate "the graph". Take for example two triangles and a circle on six points: In both graphs, you have six points and every point has degree two.

Comment: Is it then possible to generate *a* graph with such properties? Just any graph. Thanks!

Comment: Possible: Yes, this is a finite problem. However, I don't know of an algorithm to do it, so you either have to wait for someone else to come up with one or design one yourself.

Comment: So far I've figured a way to make this work with a given `l`, but `n` must be restricted to (multiples of) `2^l`. Thanks a lot of the help. Let's wait and see.

Comment: Use a circulant graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph which works for every $\ell,n$ such that $0\le\ell\le n-1$ and $\ell n$ is even.  If $\ell n$ is odd, no graph exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, you want every node to have the same weight. This is of course only possible if $n \geq \ell + 1$. Now assume we have such parameters. Pick $\ell+1$ vertices and form a complete graph on them. Continue, until you only have $k \leq \ell$ vertices left. Now there are two cases:

1. $\ell - k$ is odd. Then form a complete graph on the remaining $k$ vertices, now every remaining is still missing $\ell - k-1$ edges, an even number. Remove an edge $(v,w)$ from the previous graphs and connect a remaining vertex to both $v$ and $w$, until everyone has the desired degree. You will have to remove 
   $$\frac{k(\ell - k)}{2}$$
   edges, which is possible, as each complete graph generated before contains 
   $$\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2}$$ edges.
2. $\ell - k$ is even. Then do not form the complete graph but rather connect every vertex directly to $\ell$ vertices by removing edges. Once again, there are enough edges to remove. This only works if $\ell$ is even, but we can assume $\ell$ even due to the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), which states that if $\ell$ and $n$ are both odd, then such a graph does not exist.